# artifactory 6.8.7 won't start as can't connect to access server

Tags: artifactory

Since upgrading to 6.8.7 using the rpm on RHEL 7, using systemctl start artifactory fails

Looking in the log its failing at this point

```
2019-03-16 09:50:28,952 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:593) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8040/access (bundled) source: detected
2019-03-16 09:50:29,379 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:353) - Waiting for access server...
2019-03-16 09:50:30,625 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientHttpException:41) - Unrecognized ErrorsModel by Access. Original message: Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
2019-03-16 09:50:30,634 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:364) - Could not ping access server: {}
org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 404:Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
```

Previously we would get

```
2019-03-13 09:56:06,293 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:593) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8040/access (bundled) source: detected
2019-03-13 09:56:06,787 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:353) - Waiting for access server...
2019-03-13 09:56:24,068 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:360) - Got response from Access server after 17280 ms, continuing.
```

Any suggestions on debugging whether this access server has started ?

Further to this I found logs showing when it worked it used to start a jar file

```
2019-03-08 09:19:11,609 [localhost-startStop-2] [INFO ] (o.j.a.AccessApplication:48) - Starting AccessApplication v4.1.48 on hostname.nexor.co.uk with PID 5913 (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-4.1.48.jar started by artifactory in /)
```

Now when i look I find /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/ is empty so there is no jar file to run

The rpm did deliver an access.war file and that is there

```
$ ls -l /opt/jfrog/artifactory/webapps
total 104692
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 51099759 Mar 14 12:14 access.war
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 56099348 Mar 14 12:14 artifactory.war
```

Is there some manual step I can run to expand this war file to get the jar (as you can guess I am not up on my java apps)

Answer (score 4):

Eventually got it working by deleting the empty /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access directory and a new one containing the required jar files got created.

Not sure why this happened but that got it working for me

Comment: Thanks Alec. The above suggested solution worked for me as well `rm -rf /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access && systemctl restart artifactory.service`

Comment: For me this did not help, it was a failed database migration for this "access" service which I could not see in the main log, just in the catalina log. After fixing the database the service was able to start.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem on CentOS 7, the solution was downgrade the newly updated java packages by running this command:

```
yum downgrade java-1.8.0*
```

After that restart the artifactory:

```
systemctl restart artifactory
```

Comment: This solution worked for me too.  Redhat 7; Artifactory 6.x; Redhat OpenJdk 1.8.0_292 caused the issue.  Had to downgrade to 1.8.0_282.    Time to upgrade Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port number under your `tomcat\conf\server.xml` from `8081` to a different, unused port. Then, restart the Artifactory service to ensure the change takes effect.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: @Rajan: While that's good advice, this answer doesn't provide _any_ code (though it does prescribe a specific configuration change). I do agree that additional explanation would be valuable, though, and hope Binoy edits their answer to offer it.