# Unable to request the metadata service Service-Id after upgrading to Artifactory 6.9.1 from 6.0.2

Tags: artifactory

I have upgraded a few test instances of our Artifactory 6.0.2 Installation to version 6.9.1 using the provided instructions found at:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory

I have tried both the yum upgrade and rpm installation pathways, and would like to end the installation with no error messages in the log files to minimize any potential issues from such errors.

After installation and many manual remediation steps I have reached an error `"Unable to request the Metadata Service Service-Id"` that I cannot find Google results for:

`2019-04-09 16:22:13,409 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.m.s.s.ArtifactoryMetadataClientConfigStore:111) - Unable to request the Metadata Service Service-Id`

`2019-04-09 16:22:13,409 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.m.s.MetadataEventServiceImpl:188) - Unable to init the Metadata client. The Metadata Event pipeline will be disabled.`

I have tried both the yum upgrade and rpm installation pathways.

After the upgrades, I noticed errors in the Catalina and Artifactory log files and followed the google search results regarding those error messages (added below my question for posterity):

(1)  Created: 
`/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/access/etc/bootstrap.creds`

```
 Containing:
```

`access-admin@127.0.0.1=NEW_PASSWORD`

(2)  Removed access folder:

`rm -rf /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access`

(3)  Changed permissions of Artifactory directories:

`cd /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/
chown -R artifactory:artifactory .`

(4)  EDITED the `artifactory.system.properties` file adding:

`artifactory.pathChecksum.migration.job.enabled=true`

(5)  *Enabled sha 256 migration by adding this content to this same file:*

`##SHA2 Migration block
artifactory.sha2.migration.job.enabled=true
artifactory.sha2.migration.job.queue.workers=5`

(5)  Finally, `Rebooted instance`.

Yet the errors including `The Metadata Event pipeline will be disabled` persist.

I expect that the final state of the Artifactory server will be such that there are no error messages in the Artifactory nor Catalina log files.

Any assistance on remediating this error so that i can deploy the latest Artifactory build will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

## ======================

*Here are some of the ERROR LOGS WHICH INITIATED CHANGES SHOWN ABOVE:*

(1)  `2019-03-27 05:03:22,872 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientHttpException:41) - Unrecognized ErrorsModel by Access. Original message: Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
2019-03-27 05:03:22,872 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:364) - Could not ping access server: {}
org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 404:Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found.`

(2)`2019-03-27 05:06:53,235 [art-exec-3] [INFO ]
(o.a.s.j.m.s.Sha256MigrationJobDelegate:216) - SHA256 migration job (for existing artifacts) is disabled and will not run, there are 52496 artifacts without SHA256 values in the database.  Future versions of Artifactory may enforce this migration as a prerequisite for upgrades.`

(3) `2019-04-04 16:20:10,951 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [WARN ] (o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:550) - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-4.2.0.jar!/org/jfrog/access/rest/config/JerseyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-4.2.0.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/SystemResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'backupSubResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-4.2.0.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/backup/BackupSubResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'backupServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'importerExporter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessImporterExporterImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setServerBootstrap' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bootstrap initial access credentials.`

Comment: I believe the issue you are facing is because there is no access api exposed by artifactory. this might be because of the access folder deleted. Also your artifactory is not down because of this, right ? It's up and running ?

Comment: @error404 NO, my Artifactory instance is NOT down:  I have upgraded a test instance.  I had been receiving the error message:  `org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 404:Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found
` and followed the suggested resolution step here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196720/artifactory-6-8-7-wont-start-as-cant-connect-to-access-server

Comment: That post suggested the removal of said directory to remediate the observed issue.  I can attempt another upgrade without removing this access folder but will need a different resolution step to get past the error message `org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 404:Failed on executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found`

Comment: one of the comment also states that it was unsuccessful once. You . can try a test upgrade from 6.0.2 to 6.9.1. Also there is no db migration in this, right ? While upgrading also check in case the db driver needs to be updated as well ? Also what is the db you are using derby or postgres ?

Comment: @error404, No DB migration, instance was just upgraded in-place.  The DB driver is fine.  We use the default derby database.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback @error404.

We ended up opening a ticket with Jfrog support (https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-18939) who was able to replicate the issue and subsequently marked the ticket as "Fix Version/s:  6.10.0"

Although not strictly stated, I assume this Fix Version update implies that the described issue will be remediated in the next release.